# Auto increment COUNTIF range when inserting a row within the range

Tags: excel

I have several COUNTIF statements based on a RANGE of rows. Whenever I insert a new ROW into the range (or even inserting a row after the last item in the range) the COUNTIF range limit does not change.

I have tried standard formulas and even array formulas (Ctrl-Shift-enter) but no luck.

Here is a sample formula: 
=COUNTIF(C2:C24,"*" & "CD-A-1" & "*")-(COUNTIF(B2:B24,"E1"))

if I insert a row within the 2-24 row range I would like the COUNTIF range to increase to 25 to reflect the added row.

Is there another way to build this formula?

Comment: The range should expand automatically unless you are adding it onto the end (the last row:24->25).

Comment: Yes.. but for some reason the range is NOT expanding when I insert a row within the range. I am baffled.

Comment: hmmmm... I changed a setting in the options to Enable Iterative Calculation, then I rebooted and it seems to work. Not sure if that change mad the difference, but thanks for you comment.

Comment: Ah, right.  I had forgotten that there *are* user options/settings that can turn this off (it's very unusual for this to be disabled).

Comment: You might want to post what you did as the answer to help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to ensure that your reference will "follow" the size of your range is to define the range as a table, and then use the table column reference:

1. Select the range.
2. Go to `Home > Format as Table`
3. Instead of `=COUNTIF(C2:C24,"" & "CD-A-1" & "")-(COUNTIF(B2:B24,"E1"))`, use `=COUNTIF(YourTable[YourSecondColumn],"" & "CD-A-1" & "")-(COUNTIF(YourTable[YourFirstColumn],"E1"))`